# Is there something like data-* attributes for css?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to pass a value that's set in a stylesheet so it can be read by javascript/jQuery? I thought of creating an invisible element and giving it a value, but then I would have to include that element in all the pages, which is pretty hacky. Just want to know if there's an alternative to that.

I have a js resize script for images that resizes based on area instead of height or width, so I can't feed it a maxwidth or maxheight, per se. if you give it 100, it makes the area of an image = 100^2. I suppose I could set the maxWidth of the element to twice the number I want, but I'm just wondering if there's a classier way to pull it off.

Comment: It's possible, but can you explain in detail why? The request seems odd.

Comment: I explained what I need it for, but i can expand on it a little

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, browsers throw away attributes they don't understand, so unfortunately you can't just inject your own data-*. I think you might have to do it via a hidden element, something like below, which uses the [content](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp) attribute:

```
# styles.css
.data {
  display: none;
  content: "my data variable"
}

# index.html
<span class="data"></span>


# javascript
myData = $(".data").css('content')
```

**Update**

Playing around in Chrome, it looks like you can set the 'content' of an image and it won't show up. So you could do

```
# styles.css
img {
  content: "100"
}
```

Not sure how well that works cross browser though, also looking at the w3c spec, it says that 'content' has to be used with :before or :after, so not sure if you'll run into validation issues there.

Comment: The first example works if you use `css` instead of `attr`. http://jsfiddle.net/VjF3d/1/

Comment: neat! I'm not finding it in the w3c spec. Is it spec to do .data:after {content: "<p>element</p>"}? so that the content could be referenced with javascript?

Comment: I'm trying what you coded above using jsfiddle and the content on the element itself doesn't even seem to be working in Chrome :( http://jsfiddle.net/cutcopypaste/c7nqd/

Comment: Here's the doc, http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-content. I think you'll need to do .data:after, not sure about putting html tags inside.

Comment: Using the jsfiddle from @Dennis (above) you can see it in action, jsfiddle.net/VjF3d/1. Although it looks like the jQuery selector gets weird if you are using it with :after... But I think that is a question for a jquery guru.

Comment: I set it aside for the time being; from my fiddle and the other one it looks like the content only shows up if jquery grabs it, rather on the page (if you remove `display: none` there's no change, at least in chrome). interesting

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use javascript to query the actual element, and read its properties that way? Then you don't rely on the CSS at all.

`$('someDiv').getWidth()`